# Static IP assignment 3750X - DHCP Override

Tags: vlan, dhcp, ip-address, interface, cisco-3750

I have a 3750X that I am running some testing with. I have a VLAN interface that is using 10.10.10.254/21 as it's primary IP and 192.168.10.254/24 as it's secondary IP. See below:

```
interface Vlan10
 description Workstations
 ip address 10.10.10.254 255.255.248.0
 ip address 192.168.10.254 255.255.255.0 secondary
 no ip redirects
```

I also have a DHCP pool that is handing out IPs from the 10.10.10.x network, but **not** the 192.168.10.x network.

I go to plug in my laptop to a port on the switch and it automatically assigns an IP from the 10.10.10.x network. When I attempt to statically assign a random IP of 192.168.10.227/24, I am unable to ping the gateway in this case, 192.168.10.254.

Here are some factors:

-No other device is confirmed to be using 192.168.10.227.

-When I run `show mac-address table` filtering the interface that I am plugged into, I see the laptop plugged in, which is good.

-When I run `sh arp` filtering the MAC address again, no entry is showing for the 192.168 or 10. network.

```
CHS_3750X_STACK#show arp | i 57ee
CHS_3750X_STACK#
```

**My question:**

When I run a DHCP pool within the Cisco 3750X, am I unable to assign a static IP to my machine, even though it is within the subnet of what is stated on the interface VLAN?

Comment: Do you have IP routing enabled on the switch?

Comment: I do have ip routing enabled.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full switch configuration.

Comment: I can try to add as much as I can, without pasting the whole `sh run` in here. What do you need specifically? Or would you rather prefer the whole `sh run` minus the interface configuration?

Comment: Paste the entire configuration. You have a 30,000 character limit, and the Preformatted-text option (`{}`) will create a scroll box.

Comment: Will do. I will need to go through and omit a few things since this will eventually become a production environment. Bear with me. Thanks

Comment: What you do is obfuscate any public addresses and passwords. Private addresses like you have are fine.

Comment: I’m more suspicious of your laptop.

Comment: This ended up being a configuration issue with the port I was plugged into with my laptop. The configuration on the interface was set to trunking rather than `switchport access VLAN10`. Once I set the interface to `switchport mode access` and `switchport access vlan 10` then I was able to see the ARP entry along with being able to route outside the network. @RonMaupin since your moderator, what would you like for me to do with this question?

Comment: You should answer the question and accept your answer (probably have to wait a couple of days to accept it), or you could simply delete the whole question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a configuration issue with the port I was plugged into with my laptop. The configuration on the interface was set to trunking rather than `switchport access VLAN10`. Once I set the interface to `switchport mode access` and `switchport access vlan 10` then I was able to see the ARP entry along with being able to route outside the network.